# Слушать System.in консоли в Java

Tags: java, консоль

Здравствуйте. У меня в программе ожидается приём команды с com-порта или ввод данных в консоли. Необходимо как-то понять, что были введены данные и уйти на модуль работы с ними.

Как слушать или узнать, было ли что-то введено в консоль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `System.сonsole()`. Например:

```
System.out.print("Enter something:");
String input = System.console().readLine();
```

Но такое решение не будет работать при тестировке в IDE т.к. `System.сonsole()` будет всегда возвращать `null`.
Подробнее:
[Java System.Console IDEs and testing](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html)

Решение, которое работает в IDE:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = br.readLine();
```

Comment: Я попробую, но Ваше решение кажется очень даже не плохим.

Comment: Всё таки блокирует. Ожидается readLine().

Comment: Помогло. if(br.ready()) { br.readLine }

Answer (score 0):

А можно воспользоваться куда более удобным сканнером

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scanner.nextLine();
int n = scanner.nextInt(); //а вот и главное удобство
```

Comment: Это будет блокировать ожидание команды с порта.

Comment: Scanner реализован с помощью регулярных выражений, поэтому если нужно читать из консоли много данных, он будет работать медленно. [(Link)](https://www.acm-test.bsu.by/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Java#Scanner)

Comment: @NekoSin4eG, `br.readLine();` (см. мой ответ ниже) по идее не должен блокировать.